# Using Java & Gradle to build a maven project from github

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, github, gradle

I need help with the following problem:

Right now, I want to use my Java Gradle Project to build this github-project:
https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper but the project but it's a maven project. 
I found a plugin for adding github projects as dependencies but it fails here.

An alternative would be to use this jenkins here: https://ci.destroystokyo.com/job/Paper/

However here I'm struggling to make my gradle always use the newest build without having to reasign the chaning version numbers by hand.

Can someone help me out because I have no idea what and how to add to the build.gradle.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I found the Maven-Syntax for the correct pull here:

https://paper.readthedocs.io/en/paper-1.11/developers/#plugin-developers

But when I try to convert the information to Gradle I still fail when I try to leave out the version so that Gradle would fetch the latest one. Can someone provide a valid snipped for this? I have never done this before.

Comment: create maven project first then convert it to gradle . Please refer https://www.credera.com/blog/custom-application-development/converting-spring-boot-project-maven-gradle-sts/

Comment: Why don't you use Jar library of PaperMC/Paper project? then add it as dependency to your Gradle project

Comment: I don't want to use the regular jar because I want the project to update itself without me having to download the new fixes every two days.

Comment: "I found a plugin for adding github projects as dependencies but it fails here." -> give us details

Comment: I tried using jitpack (https://jitpack.io/) to compile the git for me but the errorlog spoke about not being able to find the correct project.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this guy](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependency-from-an-arbitrary-url-again/7359/7), you can use a fake `ivy` repository.

As `https://ci.destroystokyo.com/job/Paper/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar` points on the latest build, just set up your repository like this :

```
repositories {    
    ivy {
        url "https://ci.destroystokyo.com/job/Paper/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/"
        layout 'pattern' , {
            ivy '[module]-ivy.xml'
            artifact '[module](.[ext])'
        }
    }
}
```

And then, use the dependency (the group is not relevant here)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'anything:paperclip'
}
```

It will get the right file

```
$ gradle build
Download https://ci.destroystokyo.com/job/Paper/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar
...
```